# How to link to specific element on a differant page and execute jQuery script on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Im trying to figure out if its possible to link to specific element on a page in such a way that it would trigger jQuery Toggle.

[How the page is by default.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxP0Y.png)

[Links to an element and triggers slideToggle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZB6w.png)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".team-info").hide();
  $(".list-element").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".team-info").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

Well... Hope it makes some sort of sense. Sorry if it doesnt, but Im very new to html5 and jQuery. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks :)

Comment: i dont see any problem with that

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Comment: no, the jQuery works. my problem is that I would like it to automatically trigger when I click on the appropriate link in the navbar from another page.

Comment: desired effect e.g. :
1. You start on the index.html page
2. click on the 'Origen' link in the navbar
3. teams.html page opens and text is visible under 'Origen' badge.
4. all of the others are hidden

Comment: If these are static pages, why aren't they already designed so that the correct menu is opened by default instead of requiring a click? the siblings or next elements in page2 can't be accessed with .next(...) from page1

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the problem solved by utilizing jquery and jquery-UI Libraries and calling the .accordion() method on the desired element. You may view the JSFiddle [Here](http:////jsfiddle.net/o6vaw39s/) -- You may also view the code below.

In the HTML file I created one container that holds all of the sub-containers that make up the menu system

```
<div id="Dropdowns">
  <h3>
    Test 1
  </h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      This is test 1's content
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>
    Test 2
  </h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      This is test 2's content
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>
    Test 3
  </h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      This is test 3's content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the JS file I wrote a few small lines that called the .accordion() method as mentioned.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#Dropdowns").accordion();
    });
});
```

If you want to modify the way that the dropdown menus look, don't include the CSS that comes with libraries and write your own :)